# He is picky about food(,) so he only eats what he likes

Tags: punctuation, commas

1. He is picky about food so he only eats what he likes.
2. He is picky about food, so he only eats what he likes.

---

Which one is correct? Do we have to put a comma before 'so' or not?

Answer (score 13):

Punctuation should be understood as being less about "rules" than about "clarity". In this case, the comma is optional.  A comma is generally used before a conjunction that links two independent clauses, as is the case here. However the two clauses are quite short and we often omit the comma in this case.

You may use a comma here, if you feel it improves clarity. You may omit it if you feel it is unnecessary.

Comment: And your last two sentences demonstrate this perfectly!

Comment: To emphasize: this is purely a matter of taste, and different educated English writers will chose differently.  (I would always use the comma but I tend to use a lot of commas).

Comment: @Johnny I don't think that is an accident.

Comment: @MartinBonner … but if you don't think, [comma!] that *is* an accident :)

Comment: @MartinBonner, nor do I, just thought I'd put a neon sign over it in case it was too subtle for some learners! 

Comment: There's some weird "say a word too many times and it starts sounding wrong" think going on here because neither of your last two sentences look right to me.